# Is there any way we can capture ADF data flow activity logs?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I was trying to log the data flow activity information by using the data flow activity's output object which has a key named 'metrics' which contains 'RowsRead' and 'RowsWritten' but sometimes when data flow activity insert data into database, the metrics show 'NULL' value although records were read and written into database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that in ADF

You can create a parameterized stored procedure to do this activity.

Then call that Stored Procedure in ADF pipeline to store the logs in Database.

You can follow [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6320/logging-azure-data-factory-pipeline-audit-data/) link to know how to develop that Stored Procedure and invoke the same in your ADF pipeline

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure setting for logging level in 'dataflow activity' is set to verbose/detailed.